# Prove that $\overline{A} - A \subset A'$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $\overline{A}-A \subset A'$

I did the following:

Let $x \in \overline{A}$ $\wedge x \not \in A' $

$\forall r_x>0$ $\{B(x,r_x) \cap \overline{A} \not = \emptyset\}$

$\implies \forall r_x>0$ $\{B(x,r_x) - \{x\}\cap \overline{A} \not = \emptyset\}$

$\implies \forall r_x>0$ $\{B(x,r_x) - \{x\}\cap A' \not = \emptyset\}$ Because $A' \subset \overline{A}$

$\implies x \in A'$

$\therefore \overline{A}-A \subset A'$

Comment: Is $A'$ the derived set of $A$?

Comment: Is the accumulation point set

Answer (score 1):

$\overline A= A\cup A^{'}$.

Since $x\in \overline A$ but $x\notin A$, so $x\in A^{'}$.

Thus $\overline A\setminus A\subset A^{'}$.